# why is the answer 21,845 and not 218,450?

Tags: arithmetic, estimation

How can you tell whether

$$\frac{(250,000)(5.47)}{6.26}$$

is closer to 21,845 or 218,450 without calculating it exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the answer is wrong. $250000\cdot5.47/6.26\approx218450$. Here's the [Wolfram Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=250000+times+5.47+divided+by+6.26)

Comment: This is a great example indicating the value in estimating an answer prior to computing it. $5.47/6.26$ is larger than $5/7$ which is $0.7142857...>7/10$. So the true answer is greater than $7*25,000=175,000$.

Comment: @Karl My own estimation went like this:  6.26 is a little more than 5.47, but not much, so the answer must be less than 250,000, but not much.  So the answer is certainly nothing like 21,845. (On review, I see that T. Bongers said something much like this below.)

Comment: What makes you think the answer is 21,845?

Comment: I've edited the question the reflect what I believe cliff is asking, which agrees with the answer provided by T. Bongers below.

Answer (score 11):

If we just estimate by orders of magnitude, using the fact that

$$5.47 \approx 6.26$$

(at least up to factors of $10$ this is true), then

$$\frac{250,000 \cdot 5.47}{6.26} = 250,000 \cdot \frac{5.47}{6.26} \approx 250,000 \cdot 1$$

so the answer should be on the scale of hundred-thousands. Alternatively, as powers of $10$, the answer should *rougly* be

$$\frac{10^5 \cdot 10^1}{10^1} = 10^{5 + 1 - 1} = 10^5$$

again suggesting an answer on the order of a hundred thousand.